# How to check if last k commands ran successfully

Tags: bash

I am running a couple of bash commands and want to check if all of them ran successfully at the end. How should I go about this?

This is what I tried.

```
$ man # command 1 with exit status 1
What manual page do you want?

$ res1=$? # command 2 with exit status 0
# this also stores exit code of previous code i.e 1

$ res2=$? # storing exit code of previous command i.e 0

# Now I want to check if all previous commands worked fine with their exit codes
$ echo $res1 && $res
1
0: command not found
```

What is incorrect with my current approach. Or What should be the right thing to do? Is there a better way to generalize it for last k commands.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You `echo $res` but then ask `$res` to be executed as a command?  thus 'command not found' is valid as I'm not aware of a 0 command either.   The `&&` as you specified it breaks the commands and executes the following ONLY IF the first part executed successfully; thus `$res` was attempted to be executed; but 0 is invalid... thus error

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems as this too

id solve my problem in this way

first, I wrote a function that checks the status of the command I run in my script

```bsh
function show_process_status() {
    if [ $? == 0 ]; then 
        echo $1
    else
        echo $2
        break
    fi
}
```

then in my script, I call this function after any command that I run, for example :

```bsh
function update_system (){
    echo "start updating system"
    sudo apt-get update -y
    show_process_startus "repos updated successful" "An error occurred on updating repos"
    if [[ $1 == "full" ]]; then
        sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
        show_process_startus "system updated successful" "An error occurred on updating systems"
    elif [[ $1 == "fix" ]]; then 
        sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
        show_process_startus "update fix missing successful" "An error occurred on fix missing"
        sudo apt-get update
    fi
}
```

in the `show_process_status` function I get two-argument the first one is printed when the code run and exits successfully and the second one is used when the command exit is unsuccessful.